# Is Elasticsearch percolate the right tool for finding predefined keywords in imported RSS feed articles?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am importing some RSS feeds from the Internet, and before indexing them in Elasticsearch I want to check if the content is matching some keywords. (Simple yes/no match) Of course this could be imlemented by myself, but Elasticsearch has some very nice features that make the search a little bit more fuzzy.

I am thinking of adding a percolate query with the keywords and then sending them to elasticsearch this way to check if they are  matching. Is this the way to go or is there a better approach to solve this problem? I still want to use elasticsearch matching!

Comment: I think percolator is the best fit for the problem u described.